# Converting custom global typescript definitions to module

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6, typescript-typings, es6-modules

We are using a client side routing library called [Grapnel](https://github.com/baseprime/grapnel) in a react project. There is no definition file available for this library so I have written my own which is working but I had to create it as a global module and load the script the ol' fashioned way via a script tag. This is not optimal, as *all* the other javascript in the project is bundled by webpack.

Grapnel is installed via npm; I would like to be able to bundle Grapnel in webpack and am also curious about scenarios when we *should* write a definition as a global. 
Grapnel is written in ES5 syntax:

```
!(function(root) {

    function Grapnel(opts) {
    ....
}).call({}, ('object' === typeof window) ? window : this);
```

Therefore it needs to be instantiated as follows

```
new Grapnel({options});
```

Will it be possible for me to write the .d.ts so that I can use ES6 module import statement? Or will I need to call Grapnel as a global variable? If I must use a global definition, does that preclude bundling in webpack?

Here is my working (global) version:

```
// Type definitions for grapnel
// Project: https://github.com/baseprime/grapnel
// Definitions by: Trevor Kilvington <http://trevorgk.js.org>
// Definitions: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped
type GrapnelEvent = "navigate" | "match" | "hashchange";

interface GrapnelOptions {
  pushState?: boolean,
  root?: string,
  hashBang?: boolean
}

interface Routes {
  [route: string]: () => void;
}

declare class Grapnel  {
  constructor(init?: GrapnelOptions)
  get(route:string|RegExp)
  navigate(route:string)
  on(eventName:GrapnelEvent, callback:() => any)
  once(eventName:GrapnelEvent, callback:() => any)
  trigger(eventName:GrapnelEvent, ...eventArgs: any[] )
  context(routeContext:string, middleware: any): () => any
  path(newPath: string)
  path(clear: boolean)
  listen(routes: Routes)
}

declare module "grapnel" {
  export = Grapnel;
}
```

Thanks for any advice that can be offered. I am new to writing .d.ts but am familiar with typescript and consuming typings.